# Criterion of separability of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

When I study page 270 in Lang's algebra, I have a problem.

Let $f(X)=X^3+aX+b$ be an irreducible polynomial over a field $k$. Lang says that if char $k$ is not equal to $2,3$, then $f$ is separable.

I already know that $f$ is separable if char $k =0$, and when char $k = p>0$, $f$ is inseparable if and only if the derivative of $f$ is $0$.

But, I cannot understand the relation between char $k\neq 2,3$ and the separablity of $f$.

I need your hint or solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f$ as in your question is irreducible, then char $\neq 3$ implies it is separable, since $f'\neq 0$. Even if $f$ is not irreducible, it is still separable if char$\neq 2,3$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why the condition 'char k is not equal to 2' is required.

Comment: For non-irreducible polynomials, $f'\neq 0$ is not sufficient to guarantee separability. For example, take $f(x)=xg(x)$, where $g'=0$. Then $f$ is not separable, but $f'\neq 0$. So, if you did not know $f$ of degree $n$ is not irreducible, you may need to assume that characteristic does not divide $n!$ to ensure that it is separable.

Comment: In your example, why is f not separable? And, your comment says that given a polynomial f of degree n in k[X], if char k does not divide n!, f is inseparable if and only if f' is zero polynomial, right?

Comment: If a polynomial is separable, all its irreducible factors are, and in the example above, $g$ is not separable.

Comment: I got it!:) Thanks @Mohan

Answer (score 2):

if $f$ is an irreducible polynomial such that its derivative $f'$
is not zero then $f$ has only simple roots ie $f$ is separable.

in the case of $f=X^3 + aX + b $ is irreducible, clairly its
derivative $f' = 3X + a$ is not zero in  characters $p\not= 0$, so
it is separable over any field of characteristic $\not=3$ provided
it is irreducible over this field.